# Нужно перевести код из Паскаля в Питон

Tags: python, pascal

```
var sum, min, i: longint;
begin
  min := 400001;
  sum := 0;
  for i := 300000 to 500000 do begin
      if i mod 11 = 0 then
          if i mod 17 <> 0 then
              if i mod 23 <> 0 then
                  if i mod 41 <> 0 then
                      if i mod 103 <> 0 then begin
                          sum := sum + 1;
                          if i < min then 
                              min := i;
                      end;
  end;
  writeln(sum, min*100000.0:1:0);
end.
```

У меня есть код но он переполняет стек

```
lst =[]

for i in range(3*10**10, 5*10**10):
    if (i % 11 == 0 and i % 100000 == 0) and i % 17 != 0 and i % 23 != 0 and i % 41 != 0 and i % 103 != 0:
        lst.append(i)
print(len(lst))
print(min(lst))
```

Comment: `10 ** 10` это даже не миллион

Comment: так поставьте в паскале int64) он к 10^18)

Comment: Что-то я не вижу в паскалевском коде никаких списков или массивов.

Answer (score 2):

"В лоб":

```py
mini = 5*10**5+ 1
s = 0
for i in range(3*10**5, 5*10**5):
    if i%11 == 0:
        if i%17 != 0:
            if i%23 != 0:
                if i%41 != 0:
                    if i%103 != 0:
                        s = s + 1
                        if i<mini:
                            mini = i
print(f'{s} {mini*100000.:1.0}')
```

Упростим:

```py
mini = 500000 + 1
s = 0
for i in range(3*10**5, 5*10**5):
    if i%11 == 0 and i%17 and i%23 and i%41 and i%103:
        s += 1
        if i<mini:
            mini = i
print(f'{s} {mini*100000.:1.0}')
```

Comment: Я бы тогда написал `not i%11` если уж сокращать сравнения с нулём )